# Comprehensive List of unique Omniture/SiteCat domains

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

Googled and found nothing yet. Is there a list of all the domains that Adobe Omniture uses for its script tag calls? Sometimes we find it is "sitecat.adobe.com", but there are many variations including omniture.com, etc. Thanks!

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking here. Is it in relation to Analytics(what was mostly known as SiteCatalyst)? Also for what reason, that would help get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I want to remove all Adobe tags from my websites, but we have thousands of pages, and they don't use a common footer or anything. So we cannot just remove a common tag somewhere. We will have to write a regex to get rid of it, but we need to know *how* to find the adobe tags. Many of them are `adobetag.com` but as a legacy they use several different domains. Thx

Comment: Hi PKHunter, sorry to hear you guys are leaving our products. I will try come up with a useful list of things to look at. Were you just using SiteCatalyst, or t&t/demdex/S7 etc.

Comment: the legacy script isn't hosted by adobe. It's traditionally a file called  s_code.js hosted on your own site. Though, there's no reason you can't change the filename or embed the file contents in some other file, or even host it in some central location if they have more than 1 site, or some random tag management system. And there's no way to automate telling which js file actually made the ping to adobe. In short, there's no easy way to find which script tag actually has the adobe code in it

Comment: Right, as Crayon says, not easy. Assuming we are just talking about Adobe Analytics/SiteCatalyst here you could try the following. Browse to your site with web tools enabled, search for GET requests that went to an url with/ss/ in it. This is likely an Adobe image beacon and the server name is going to be text searchable on you wcm for the real s_code files that are doing analytics. this server can be on an Adobe domain or one of your C level DNS entries.

Comment: Thank you Crayon (colorful name :)) and Chris. 

Chris, we were using SiteCat. I think we will strip out all `s_code.js` stuff, and any `adobetag.com` references, but you're right, sometimes our teams across the world have put the code in some random files such as `omni.js` (for omniture I suppose) or some such odd names. And this ranges in the thousands. So, to make things error-proof, we wanted to find/replace all domain calls to be sure, even if stray JS code remains in some of our outlier pages. Thanks!

Comment: I also want to point out that you're just removing the base code.. there could be custom code on the page or in other random files. For example, traditionally there's the script include followed by custom code like `s.pageName="..";` and then an `s.t()` call. There could be wrapper functions elsewhere that make s.t or s.tl calls or to random plugins like s.getQueryParam. (like in link onclicks or attached via jquery, etc..) So if you simply remove the script includes, you may find yourself with javascript error(s) on your page(s) from attempting to actually call the Adobe code.

Comment: You can put like `var s = { t:function() {},tl:function() {}}` at the bottom of all your pages and it will catch most of it, but it won't catch calls to plugins or anything.. unfortunately adobe sc is not structured in such a way (like how GA is, where you supply actions/methods/settings as arguments to a single entry point) that you can make a catch-all dummy object. And javascript doesn't have a browser-compatible "catch-all" method for non-existent functions.